# Calculating Date Difference In XSLT-1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

**Note: Please don't mark this as duplicate, hear my question out please**

I'm completely new here and I've spent some time doing research, apparently all the answers are extremely vague, they only tell you what to do instead of how to do it.

Can someone please provide exactly what do i have to put in the XML file and what goes in the XSL file to get the simplistic date difference possible?

Every answer out there just throws one segment of the code but with being new I have no idea where and how to implement it so thanks for understanding my issue :) Hope you can help me

[Finding the difference between 2 dates in xslt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5544762/finding-the-difference-between-2-dates-in-xslt)

I went over this site and tried implementing the code but as you can see its producing errors

http://xsltransform.net/jz1PuP1

Comment: Your question **is** a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22376019/how-do-we-test-whether-a-date-is-within-180-days-from-today-in-xslt-in-datapower/22377178#22377178 (as well as others you could have found). There is an XSLT 1.0 answer even in your own link. --

Comment: "*Can someone please provide exactly what do i have to put in the XML file and what goes in the XSL file to get the simplistic date difference possible?*" No. You need to provide a (small example of) your XML input, the expected output, and explain what have your tried and how it failed - see: [mcve]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating Date Difference In XSL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39502587/calculating-date-difference-in-xsl)